# Multi-project .sbt build definition format breaks plugins

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, sbteclipse

According to [the sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bare-Def.html):

> The current recommendation is to use Multi-project .sbt build definition.

When I try to implement this as per the documentation's [example](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def-Examples.html), sbt no longer recognizes the sbt-assembly and sbteclipse plugins I added in:

```
./project/assembly.sbt
./project/plugins.sbt
```

It does work when I revert to a [bare .sbt build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bare-Def.html).

I'm assuming the explanation is something to do with scoping, or some additional lines I need in my `build.sbt` file.

Does anyone have the explanation? I don't think this is in the documentation. At least not anywhere that I can find it. If I'm wrong, please point me to the relevant section. Thanks!

Comment: You should not need additional lines in your `build.sbt`, but nor should this be a problem. Can you run sbt from the command line? Are you seeing any warnings?

Comment: sbt will run from the command line, but the `eclipse` task is not recognized, even though `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")` is saved in the `plugins.sbt` file.  Here is the output from sbt eclipse:  `[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
    [error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
    [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
    [error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
    [error] eclipse
    [error]        ^`

Comment: On further reflection, this seems to be a heisenbug. After changing my build.sbt into a bare definition, it still isn't working, whereas other projects that I started with are bare definition are.